# PHP Output buffering, Content Encoding Error caused by ob_gzhandler?

Tags: php, gzip, output-buffering

Can anyone explain why I am receiving the following error?

In the code, if the `echo $gz;` is commented out I receive no error (but also no output!), if it isn't I get (from Firefox),

> **Content Encoding Error**
>
> ---
>
> The page you
>   are trying to view cannot be shown
>   because it uses an invalid or
>   unsupported form of compression.

---

Thanks for your help, here's the code:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler') OR ob_start();
echo 'eh?';
$gz = ob_get_clean();
echo $gz;
```

Comment: Do you set the appropriate Content-Encoding header? 'eh?' isn't gzipped here btw.

Comment: @Kemo I wasn't setting the `Content-Encoding` header manually, no, but Firebug shows that it is set correctly anyway, I have now tried manually setting it too, but no difference. I'm aware that `"eh?"` isn't gzipped in my example - as I mention in the question, I just used that to show that the error occurs whether I return the gzipped content or not. I'll make that a bit clearer I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The output of your application should only contain one output encoding. If you have multiple chunks that are encoded differently, then the browser will get a result that it is impossible to work with. Hence the encoding error.

Kohana itself makes already use of the output buffer. If you want to combine that with your ob_gzhandler output buffer, you need to start your buffer before kohana initialized it's own. That's because output buffer are stackable. When kohana has finished it's output buffering, yours will apply:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); # your buffer:
   ob_starts and ends by kohana
```

So whenever kohana has done some output, these chunks will get passed on into your output callback ([`ob_gzhandler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php)) and will be gz-encoded.

The browser should then only get gz-encoded data as it was the output buffer at the topmost level.

### Using ob_gzhandler and manually echo'ing the buffer

If you make use of `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` to let PHP deal with the compression and you then `echo ob_get_clean()`, you will create an unreliable output. That's related to how the compression togther with output buffering works:

PHP will buffer chunks of output. That means, PHP starts to compress the output but keeps some bytes to continue compressing. So ob_get_clean() returns the so-far compressed part of the buffer. Often that result is not complete.

To deal with that, flush the buffer first:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler') OR ob_start();
echo 'eh?';
ob_flush();
$gz = ob_get_clean();
echo $gz;
```

And ensure you don't have any more output after that.

If you would have PHP reached the end of your script, it would have taken care of that: Flushing and outputting.

Now you need to manually call `ob_flush()` to explicitly make PHP push the buffer through the callbacks.

### Inspecting HTTP Compression Problems with Curl

As firefox will return an error, another tool to inspect what's causing the encoding error is needed. You can use [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) to track what's going on:

```
curl --compress -i URL
```

Will request the URL with compression enabled while displaying all response headers and the body unencoded. This is necessary as PHP transparently enables / disables compression of the `ob_gzhandler` callback based on request headers.

A response also shows that PHP will set the needed response headers as well. So no need to specify them manually. That would be even dangerously, because only by calling `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` you can not say if compression is enabled or not.

In case the compression is broken, `curl` will give an error description but would not display the body.

Following is such a curl error message provoked with an incompletely generated output by a faulty php script:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Content-Encoding: gzip
...

curl: (23) Error while processing content unencoding: invalid code lengths set
```

By adding the `--raw` switch, you can even peak into the raw response body:

```
curl --compress --raw -i URL
```

That can give an impression what's going wrong, like uncompressed parts within the body.

Comment: Oops, sorry - I just completely rewrote the question as you were typing your answer. I'll rollback if your answer solves the original problem, but as you can see in the updated question - I may have been too hasty thinking this was a Kohana problem, I'm getting the same error even if I don't route through Kohana. Thanks for your reply though - I'll give it a proper read ... now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Tried it with `curl` it seems that the response is coming through unencoded, but with `Content-Encoding: gzip` hence the error when decoding.

Comment: Test the code example I've added. It works. Tracked this down with curl and firefox.

Comment: Yeah was new to me as well with so much detail. Let me know if that solved it with Kohana as well.

Comment: I will do. Now I've had another look at it though I'm confused again, the `ob_get_clean` won't actually contain anything right, since `ob_flush` discards the buffer contents.

Comment: Thanks thats perfect solution !

Answer (score 0):

**This is what phpharo does:**

```
/** output buffring */
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== false)
{
 ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); ob_start();
}
else
{
 ob_start();
}
```